# Images which have text and links beside them

Tags: html, css, position, css-position

Hey I'm trying to embed 4 pictures with 1 text and 2 links beside it but I can't get through the last three...here is the code so far:

```
 <img src="http://developers-community.com/beta/photoshopcc.png"  align="left">
 <font size="3" style="padding: 10px;color:#008B8B;">Photoshop</font>
 <br>
 <a class="link" href="#"  style="padding:10px">Preview</a>
 <br>
 <a class="link" href="#" style="padding:10px;">Add to your page</a>
```

I tried several CSS stuff like holders and pic1, pic2, pic3, pic 4 but it seemed to work with images alone without text and links. I need to get 3 other images with the same size of this picture and same links and text beside each other. I need the images to be horizontal and the text to be vertical be side them.

Comment: probably remove `<br>` tag if you want them aligned horizontally

Comment: Couldnt guess your layout..elaborate it.

Comment: I know that, I want them the way they are but with 3 other pictures with same text and links beside each other

Comment: now if i add the same code thrice...its giving stepped layout..but you want it to be aligned vertically top..Is it.

Comment: No, I want the Images to be horizontal and the text to be vertical beside them.

Comment: I have posted my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LIke this

[**[DEMO][1](http://jsfiddle.net/R9FMM/1/)**](http://jsfiddle.net/R9FMM/1/)

css

```
.pull-left{
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: Done, sorry I'm new here :D

Answer (score 0):

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GvmRt/)

```
<div style=width:100%;float:left;">

<div  style="verticalalign:top;float:left;">
     <img src="http://developers-community.com/beta/photoshopcc.png"  align="left">
     <font size="3" style="padding: 10px;color:#008B8B;">Photoshop</font>
 <br>
     <a class="link" href="#"  style="padding:10px">Preview</a>
 <br>
     <a class="link" href="#" style="padding:10px;">Add to your page</a></div>
<div  style="verticalalign:top;float:left;">
     <img src="http://developers-community.com/beta/photoshopcc.png"  align="left">
     <font size="3" style="padding: 10px;color:#008B8B;">Photoshop</font>
 <br>
     <a class="link" href="#"  style="padding:10px">Preview</a>
 <br>
     <a class="link" href="#" style="padding:10px;">Add to your page</a></div>
<div  style="verticalalign:top;float:left;">
     <img src="http://developers-community.com/beta/photoshopcc.png"  align="left">
     <font size="3" style="padding: 10px;color:#008B8B;">Photoshop</font>
 <br>
     <a class="link" href="#"  style="padding:10px">Preview</a>
 <br>
     <a class="link" href="#" style="padding:10px;">Add to your page</a></div>
<div  style="verticalalign:top;float:left;">
     <img src="http://developers-community.com/beta/photoshopcc.png"  align="left">
     <font size="3" style="padding: 10px;color:#008B8B;">Photoshop</font>
 <br>
     <a class="link" href="#"  style="padding:10px">Preview</a>
 <br>
     <a class="link" href="#" style="padding:10px;">Add to your page</a></div>

</div>
```